# Xero OAuth 2.0 tenants list

Tags: oauth-2.0, xero-api

I have come across the following scenario during testing.

User A logs into my app and connects to Xero Company A. Going through OAuth 2.0 (offline) I get a list of tenants which only contains Company A. Can use that tenant ID all good.
User B logs in and connects to Xero Company B. Going through OAuth 2.0 (offline) they select their company BUT the list of tenants returned does not have Company B and does include Company A.

Why is that?

Comment: It sounds like you might still be querying the /connections endpoint using the token for User A. Have you debugged and confirmed that you're not mixing tokens up?